# Corregir la siguiente función

Tags: dataframe, function

Estoy creando la siguiente función para calcular la variable **LeafArea_rf_model**. La función realiza el procedimiento correctamente cuando tengo uso los mismos nombres de las columnas en la nueva base de datos, por ejemplo:

```
calculate_LeafArea_rf <- function(data, LeafLength = "LengthLeaf",
                                  sp = "sp",
                                  LeafWidth = "WidthLeaf") {
  # Leer la base de datos
  df <- read_excel("C:/Users/Alex/Google Drive/GitHub/LeafArea/inst/tests/testdata/df.xlsx")
  n <- sample(1:2,
              size=nrow(df),
              replace=TRUE,
              prob=c(0.8,0.2))
  treino <- df[n==1,]
  teste <- df[n==2,]
  set.seed(123)
  controle <- caret::trainControl(
    method='repeatedcv',
    number=6,
    repeats=2,
    search='grid',
  )
  
  grid <- base::expand.grid(.mtry=c(1:10))
  
  gridsearch_rf <- caret::train(LeafArea ~ LeafLength + LeafWidth + sp,
                                data = treino,
                                method = 'rf',
                                trControl = controle,
                                ntree=5,
                                tuneGrid = grid)
  
  pred_treino <- predict(gridsearch_rf, treino)
  
  pred_teste <- predict(gridsearch_rf, teste)
  
  mse_treino <- mean((pred_treino - treino$LeafArea)^2)
  mse_teste <- mean((pred_teste - teste$LeafArea)^2)
  
  mae_treino <- mean(abs(pred_treino - treino$LeafArea))
  mae_teste <- mean(abs(pred_teste - teste$LeafArea))
  
  mape_treino <- mean(abs((pred_treino - treino$LeafArea) / treino$LeafArea))
  mape_teste <- mean(abs((pred_teste - teste$LeafArea) / teste$LeafArea))
  
  r_squared_treino <- 1 - (sum((treino$LeafArea - pred_treino)^2) / sum((treino$LeafArea - mean(treino$LeafArea))^2))
  r_squared_teste <- 1 - (sum((teste$LeafArea - pred_teste)^2) / sum((teste$LeafArea - mean(teste$LeafArea))^2))
  
  print('Métricas de evaluación en el conjunto de entrenamiento')
  print(paste("MSE:", mse_treino))
  print(paste("MAE:", mae_treino))
  print(paste("MAPE:", mape_treino))
  print(paste("R²:", r_squared_treino))
  
  print('Métricas de evaluación en el conjunto de prueba')
  print(paste("MSE:", mse_teste))
  print(paste("MAE:", mae_teste))
  print(paste("MAPE:", mape_teste))
  print(paste("R²:", r_squared_teste))
  
  # Asegurarse de que las columnas necesarias estén presentes
  required_columns <- c(LeafLength, LeafWidth, sp)
  data_columns <- colnames(data)
  
  if (!all(required_columns %in% data_columns)) {
    stop(paste("Las columnas '", paste(required_columns, collapse = "', '"), "' son necesarias en la base de datos. "))
  }
  
  data$sp <- as.factor(data$sp)
  
  # Predecir valores de sqrt_LeafArea en la nueva base de datos
  data$LeafArea_rf_model <- predict(gridsearch_rf, newdata = data)
  
  print(data)
  # Devolver la base de datos con la nueva variable calculada
  return(data)
}
```

Cuando la ejecuto con la siguiente base de datos:

```
> dput(df_result_outlier)
structure(list(Culture = c("S. quitoense", "S. quitoense", "S. quitoense", 
"S. quitoense", "S. quitoense", "S. quitoense", "S. betaceum", 
"S. betaceum", "S. betaceum", "S. betaceum", "S. betaceum", "S. betaceum"
), LL = c(25, 27, 27, 56, 56, 56, 25, 27, 28, 56, 56, 56), LW = c(57, 
56, 57, 53, 54, 53, 57, 56, 57, 53, 54, 55)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

El resultado es perfecto:

```
> df_result <- calculate_LeafArea_rf(df_result_outlier, 
+                                    LeafLength = "LeafLength",
+                                    sp = "sp",
+                                    LeafWidth = "LeafWidth")
[1] "Métricas de evaluación en el conjunto de entrenamiento"
[1] "MSE: 4572.49716886846"
[1] "MAE: 25.3340392538772"
[1] "MAPE: 0.149699140338004"
[1] "R²: 0.969093525875744"
[1] "Métricas de evaluación en el conjunto de prueba"
[1] "MSE: 8102.0909810061"
[1] "MAE: 40.0015811640212"
[1] "MAPE: 0.276656035583078"
[1] "R²: 0.94606765364782"
             sp LeafLength LeafWidth LeafArea_rf_model
1  S. quitoense         25        57          391.9464
2  S. quitoense         27        56          404.0097
3  S. quitoense         25        57          391.9464
4  S. quitoense         56        53         1555.3302
5  S. quitoense         56        54         1766.8037
6  S. quitoense         56        55         1766.8037
7   S. betaceum         25        57          372.7078
8   S. betaceum         27        56          404.0097
9   S. betaceum         28        57          404.0097
10  S. betaceum         56        53         1555.3302
11  S. betaceum         56        54         1766.8037
12  S. betaceum         56        55         1766.8037
```

Sin embargo, cuando cambio los nombres de las columnas de la misma base de datos, me aparece un error. Por ejemplo:

```
> dput(df_result_outlier)
structure(list(sp = c("S. quitoense", "S. quitoense", "S. quitoense", 
"S. quitoense", "S. quitoense", "S. quitoense", "S. betaceum", 
"S. betaceum", "S. betaceum", "S. betaceum", "S. betaceum", "S. betaceum"
), LL = c(25, 27, 25, 56, 56, 56, 25, 27, 28, 56, 56, 56), LW = c(57, 
56, 57, 53, 54, 54, 57, 56, 57, 53, 54, 55)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Al ejecutar la función en la misma base de datos anterior pero con los nombres de columnas diferentes, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
> df_result <- calculate_LeafArea_rf(df_result_outlier, 
+                                    LeafLength = "LL",    # Cambiado a "LeafLength"
+                                    sp = "sp",       # Cambiado a "sp"
+                                    LeafWidth = "LW")     # Cambiado a "LeafWidth"
[1] "Métricas de evaluación en el conjunto de entrenamiento"
[1] "MSE: 4138.63813398654"
[1] "MAE: 24.5457389613682"
[1] "MAPE: 0.159611961439305"
[1] "R²: 0.97308883030464"
[1] "Métricas de evaluación en el conjunto de prueba"
[1] "MSE: 12093.5975105349"
[1] "MAE: 42.2986067477396"
[1] "MAPE: 0.272276659211742"
[1] "R²: 0.902282785106287"
**Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'sp')
In addition: There were 36 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Called from: model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels)**
```

De antemano, muchas gracias
Alex

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Además, pon en las etiquetas con qué lenguaje estás trabajando. Lee [ask].